# Change default scope of "Find Usages" in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run "Find Usages" in the latest version of IntelliJ (2021.2.3 Ultimate Edition) it uses the scope "Project and Libraries" by default whereas I usually want to limit the scope to "Project". Therefore my current workflow is

1. right-click on the thing of interest (class, method, etc.) and select "Find Usages" from the menu
2. in the results panel click on the settings icon (gear wheel)
3. in the dialog that appears (see below) change the scope to "Project"
4. click "Find" to re-run with the correct scope

[image]

Every time I run "Find Usages" I have to go through the steps above, because it always defaults back to using the "Project and Libraries" scope. Is there some way I can change it to use the "Project" scope by default instead?

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: @y.bedrov 2021.2.3 Ultimate Edition

Comment: Do you mean that scope is rested on IDE restart?

Comment: @y.bedrov no, the "Project and Libraries" scope is used the next time Find Usages is run

Comment: Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253911

Comment: This is still an issue in 2023. As y.bedrov suggested, please vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253911/Find-Usages-should-use-the-previous-scope-by-default-or-allow-a-default-scope-to-be-specified-in-the-preferences